# Does this question violate the Stack Overflow guidelines?

Tags: discussion, flags

I saw a question today where someone asked the community to recommend a good programming book. This question was (to my surprise) closed because for being a duplicate of this question: *[The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)*

This question has over 4,000 upvotes and is locked. Am I missing something? To me it looks like this question should be removed as it attempts to recommend a book or off-site resource.

Should this post be flagged/removed?

Comment: couldn't all of that information be kept in the documents section of SO? I see the duplicate you posted, but that doesn't really answer my question. Is this post a violation?

Comment: Yes the post is in violation. I don't know what post you're talking about, but it will probably be deleted (if it hasn't been already).

Comment: I think the post you linked to is an exception (cc @4castle) because 1) C++ is so complex that having a list of perfect and near-perfect C++ books maintained by experts is a must 2) the folks frequenting the [c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++) tag are extremely concerned about misinformation created by people who didn't learn C++ properly.

Comment: @dorukayhan Whoops, I meant the post which was marked as a duplicate was in violation. I'm well aware of that dupe target being a special case. I guess I read the question wrong.

Comment: @dorukayhan should it go in the documentation though? does it really need to be a question? I am just trying to learn where the line is. I have seen many posts deleted for trying to do similar things.

Comment: The big difference here, I think, is that this one is actively supported by its community.

Comment: No, it should not be in Documentation. First of all, Documentation is in Beta and therefore is not a good location for anything lasting. Secondly, lists of books do not belong in Documentation. How is a list of books an Example? A Topic? At best it could be in the Remarks of an introduction topic to a language tab, but even that is pushing it.

Comment: So I guess what I have learned yesterday/today is that the rules are arbitrarily enforced?