# My NAA flag got declined as if it were a custom flag

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer, specific-answer, link-only-answers

I flagged this answer: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) as it is just a list of URL's, so not really an answer. Also the question is off-topic as it asks for recommendations.

My NAA flag got declined with the reason: "declined - flags should only be used ot make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention" AFAIK NAA flags aren't specifically mod flags, and therefore this decline reasons struck me as odd.

[image]

Comment: NAA flags on positively scored or accepted answers are reviewed by moderators even if they go through community review.

Comment: That question has some history in meta. Search around. It is considered an _exception_ to the rules.

Comment: There's a long history of discussions about this specific question: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375422/is-give-me-a-collection-of-books-an-on-topic-question-on-so), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296094/delete-more-book-lists), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344603/does-this-question-violate-the-stack-overflow-guidelines)

Comment: Good to know @yivi, but then the close reason is still odd IMHO.

Comment: Well seeing that is has such history and still causes problems wouldn't the best solution be to simply remove the exception. Instead of having exception handlers do the useless work?

Comment: It's great content to have _somewhere_. Apparently an alternative to SO with all SO features is not so easy to find to put it there (nevermind the traffic and visibility).

Comment: Why don't they simply put it in a open-source GITHUB like thing? Looks easy enough to me.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that a public github site wouldn't be too hard, and would have a lot of the features we do enjoy here. A bit harder to use and manain, no second-level comments, no downvoting bad recommendations, etc, and some other things I may have not thought of. And the traffic and visibility. I agree with you that exceptions are not great to have, as they generate confusion, but there you go. :)

Comment: Ho, It's the bimonthly C++ Book list question, a 4K+ Answer/Question with 10k favorites. And 3 Diamonds holder casually talking about how to improve the answer. Perhaps we just need a bigger notification on this question.

Comment: @DragandDrop if you ask me we should just set it free. Like we do with all posts that are no longer on-topic when cleaning up a tag in for example a burnination.

Comment: "There's really only *one* valid exception to this rule, and that's when the *question* is: `Suggest me some tutorials where i can learn quick.` Don't get me wrong, it's still a bad answer - but when the question is kinda *asking* for bad answers this is to be expected. Close or flag *the question* and move on..." ([Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/165773))

Comment: To be honest, did you really think flagging a >4000-score answer with multiple meta discussions about it NAA was a good idea, and wouldn't get picked up and declined by a mod?

Comment: [Related answer by a ♦ moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286970/2675154)

Comment: @Erikvonasmuth, I wasn't aware of the Meta discussions tegarding this post. And score isn't always that relevant, especially if a post is this ancient. The site evolves and so does its moderation guidelines.

Comment: An [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354777/6560478) mod answer.

Comment: @honk, Agreed that there could be things that have value, but the case here is so off-topic (It's not even a programming problem) that this shouldn't apply. If we are here to make a collection of Pears (Q) and Apples (A), why should we keep strawberries around?

Comment: Score and views are certainly relevant for moderation, even for old content. It indicates how many people value the content. If over 4000 people upvoted something, it's not appropriate to let 5 people delete it in review imo. Also, a quick [meta search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=C%2B%2B+book) reveals many discussions, as there will likely be on posts like this. Also, you can see a mod did comment on the answer on the post this year, and it's been edited a lot recently, so you can be sure it may be old but is not inactive.

Comment: @DragandDrop I'm not so sure about that vast majority. Perhaps the C crowd will cinspire together to keep the strawberry in our collection of pears and apples. But should this group be allowed to dictate the rules? I don't think so. Also classifying moderators as Gods is highly inappropriate and blasphemous.

Comment: @Luuklag: Here's the problem with that line of thinking. It essentially ensures that the question *will* eventually be deleted, because there will be this constant pressure to delete it, and sooner or later, there will not be enough people who want to keep it to stop them from doing it. And once it's gone, it's not coming back. We've *had this discussion already*, we found a compromise, and to retract that compromise *now* is essentially going back on our word. We had a deal; reneging on it is generally not considered acting in good faith.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know and as I commented, answers positively scored and accepted get to be reviewed by moderators even if they go through the community review. I asked about this some time ago and got an answer which [may shed a bit more light into this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361607).

This comment under the answer gives additional clues:

> If a post has a positive score and review votes to delete it, the flags are marked as helpful and a system-generated "Post has a good score but received delete votes" flag is raised for moderators to review. We then go through and review each of these, both to prevent good posts from being deleted by bad reviews and to catch things like voting fraud propping up bad answers. Those posts will all be eventually reviewed by a moderator  – Brad Larson♦ Jan 9 at 17:37

Still, I think that your use of the NAA flag on that answer wasn't very enlightened.

That post **is an answer** for that question. What you want to argue is that the question is not proper for SO.

But if a question asks for a link or a list of links, a post that answers with a link can't be NAA. The problem in these cases lies with the question.

(Not that I'm super happy with these rules, as they can be confusing, and what's considered a correct action in *review* might not be consistent with what's the correct course when *flagging*... but they do make some sense).

Comment: How are these rules confusing? It seems like common sense to me that an attempted answer to an off-topic question is *still* an attempt to answer that question and thus doesn't qualify as NAA.

Comment: @BoltClock Personally, I find them confusing because you are "trained" in review queues and guidance that an answer like this should be marked for deletion, but at the same time are told that you shouldn't flag answers like this... I made peace with this, and I can follow the different guidances, but I do find them confusing, and I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one.

Comment: If review is training users to flag answers to off-topic questions as NAA just because the question is off-topic, something needs to be done about the audits probably...

Comment: @BoltClock Maybe. There are many variables you could adjust. In my opinion, it would be better to make it clearer that link only answers are deletable, without regard if they been posted under an off-topic or under an on-topic question. But I understand that goes counter to the current guidance (which I find counter-intuitive and confusing, so it's not a big surprise I'm a proponent for change).