# How does this answer the question?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

[An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48798484/linsn-led-studio-wont-connect-to-ts802-sending-card/53315614#53315614) to a question, asking why a program wouldn't connect to a TS802 sending card, (which is off-topic for SO anyway) was added today, saying:

> I had a similar problem with a faulty USB lead.
>
> Cheers, NotHarry46,

I flagged this as NAA, since it does not explain how to solve the connection issues, it just states one probable cause of the issue.

My flag got declined ("flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer").
Why that? Did I misunderstand the answer? I think it's unlikely, as another user added a comment that this is not an answer, which I and a third user upvoted, which, from my experience reviewing NATOs (New answers to old questions), suggests that they also flagged the question as NAA/VLQ.

Even if I did, at least the question should be closed (since off-topic).

Comment: It is an answer. It boils down to: 'X happened due to a faulty USB lead'. (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)

Comment: It may be that the question is the problem in this case. That question does not look like it should be on-topic for SO, IMO; but that answer (and the existing accepted answer) could be acceptable for that question.

Comment: The accepted answer is essentially the same, it also hints at a hardware fault. This new one is just more specific about the type of defect.

Comment: These kind of answers should not be deleted.  Proper troubleshooting mystifying software behavior caused by malfunctioning hardware can only be learned in the School of Hard Knocks.  Or SO, but of course that can't work when such contributions are destroyed.  It is most definitely an answer, you cannot expect the victim sharing his experience to understand why the firmware behaves like that.

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah, but Eric is right: *one* answer that says: "try other hardware" should be good enough. That other answer "i tried other hardware" doesn't add value does it.

Comment: It does not say that.  The despised answer is in fact more specific about the hardware problem.  And more likely to be the correct solution, hardware vendors don't test USB cables.

Comment: @HansPassant I agree with you, and have voted to undelete the answer. Perhaps the question deserves closure, but downvoting and deleting *one* of the possible hardware-related causes while allowing the other to remain unmolested seems illogical and arbitrary. Given the view you've voiced here, by all means add your undelete vote to mine.

Comment: The question itself is a good question, just on the wrong site. No reason to actually flag it, maybe to close as off-topic. The answers may be poor, but each points to a separate possible issue (and implying how to solve it), so are actual answers to the question. No reason to flag anything. Hardly reason to downvote, even. The vote I would heartily agree with, is the close vote on the question itself.

Comment: @Golez, with less than 3k you can only flag as offtopic, not vote.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Even if I did, at least the question should be closed (since off-topic).

And therein lies the problem.

The existing answers are poor, but are valid(ish) for this kind of question.

Instead of flagging the answer(s), flag/vote the question for closure.

Comment: I have to admit that I often don't take a look at the question before flagging an answer as NAA. TIL that I should though.

Comment: @Filnor: I forget who I learned it from, but a post on Meta awhile back expressed gratitude for learning the importance of precision and accuracy in posing here on SO. I've taken that to heart. I double check everything in a question and answer before replying just as if I were writing code.

Comment: Late close flag on [tag:led] [tag:usb]? That seems unlikely to work.

Comment: @Robert, personally, I believe that this and other similar flags on very poor quality answers on very poor quality questions should be honored, and the answers deleted. My answer here only reflects what I gathered to be the current understanding of the existing rules, despite me not [completely agreeing with them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375626/1426539). I'm trying to save the OP some frustration, since these flags **are** routinely declined by mods because of the above reasoning.